# Разбить ссылку на параметры

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Нужна помощь - не могу сообразить: в цикле получаю ссылки по типу:

```
https://vk.com/wall615115464_55 \n
https://vk.com/photo739520027_457239183?rev=1 \n
https://vk.com/video-209520128_456239021 \n
```

Нужно ссылку разбить на три параметра `type`, `owner_id` и `item_id`.
Где `type` - это `photo`, `video`, а `wall` нужно заменять на параметр `post`.

`owner_id` это первая часть цифр Идентификатор владельца. `item_id` это вторая часть Идентификатор объекта.

```
url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/likes.add?type=%s&owner_id=%s&item_id=%s&v=5.131&access_token=%s' % (
                                type, owner_id, item_id, token)
```

Пробую так:

```
my_string = "https://vk.com/video-209520128_456239021"
s=my_string.split("/")[3]
l=str.split(s)
m= ([''.join(j) for i,j in groupby (l[0], key=lambda x:x[0].isdigit())])

type = m[0]
owner_id = m[1]
item_id = m[3]
```

Как теперь прописать условие если `typ == wall` заменяем на post. При разделении на параметры минус остается у `video-` а надо так `-209520128` может кто поможет, а то шляпа какая то получается.

Comment: регулярка? 12345

Comment: В них вообще кто нибудь разбирается )

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/nv5UsC/1 попробуйте поиграться с настройками на сайте, `(?<=/)([a-z]+)(-?\d+)_(\d+)` по идее должно сработать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярное выражение: `/([a-z]+)-?(\d+)_(\d+)`

- Вытаскиваемая часть начинается со слеша
- Дальше идет 1 или более (`+`) латинская буква (`[a-z]`)
- Необязательный (`?`) дефис
- 1 или более (`+`) цифр (`\d`)
- подчеркивание
- одна или более цифр

Извлекаемые части берем в скобки, чтобы вытащить только их (а не всю сматченную строку)

Если дефис после video не разделитель, а должен относиться к числу (в чем я сильно сомневаюсь) - включите его во вторую группу: `/([a-z]+)(-?\d+)_(\d+)`

```py
import re

urls = """
https://vk.com/wall615115464_55
https://vk.com/photo739520027_457239183?rev=1
https://vk.com/video-209520128_456239021
""".strip().splitlines()


for url in urls:
    print(url)
    result = re.search(r"/([a-z]+)-?(\d+)_(\d+)", url)
    print(result.groups())
    type_name, owner_id, item_id = result.groups()
```

Вывод:

```
https://vk.com/wall615115464_55
('wall', '615115464', '55')
https://vk.com/photo739520027_457239183?rev=1
('photo', '739520027', '457239183')
https://vk.com/video-209520128_456239021
('video', '209520128', '456239021')
```

Замену `wall` на `post` делаете просто через `if`, тут не нужно чего-то особенного выдумывать:

```py
if type_name == "wall":
    type_name = "post"
```

Comment: >*остается у video- а надо так -209520128*: минус в группу перенести и класс)

Comment: @ipatev_nn я предполагаю, что минус - это просто разделитель между video и его id, я сомневаюсь то там отрицательные id используются.

Comment: Ну я ничего не предполагаю, просто из вопроса процитировал, а вы как отвечающий, конечно на свое усмотрение можете советовать

Comment: Ок, дополнил ответ

Comment: @ insolo Спасибо большое!!! Но все же запрос работает только со знаком -

Comment: @teamarden ну пользуйтесь вторым вариантом регулярки, в чем проблема. Кстати, если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым - для этого поставьте галку слева от него.

Comment: @ insolo Извини не разглядел.